# SQL add space in column string

Tags: mysql

I have an sql table named Customers.
In Customers I have the column Name.

I want to add in the column Name an space after 5 characters.

Example:

From the column "Name" with the content "name1234" i want add a space at the position 4 so that the result is "name 1234".

I have try it so but it dont work.

```
SELECT INSERT('Name',4,0, ' ')

FROM
  Customers
```

How would you do it, please help.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the column name (`'Name'` -> `Name`).

Comment: hmm still the same, i got the error "near INSERT syntax error"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to update your column values with a concatenation of the first part of the name followed by the space `' '`, followed by the rest of the name.

```
UPDATE Customers
 SET name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(name, 1, 5), 
     ' ', 
     SUBSTRING(name, 6));
```

Comment: Okay i have tried it but i get an error = "near FROM syntax error"

Comment: try again. I've changed the last substring instruction.

Comment: Okay i have tryed now the error is = "no such function SUBSTRING"

Comment: Well. What is the version of mysql you are using?

Comment: Okay i get it worked now, i have taken the latest mysql:D
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert

```
SELECT INSERT('Customers', 6, 0, ' ');
```

To update all rows:

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE
SET YOURCOL = INSERT(Customers, 6, 0, ' ');
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an example:

```
mysql> select * from CUSTOMERS;
+----+---------+-----+---------+--------+
| ID | NAME    | AGE | ADDRESS | SALARY |
+----+---------+-----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Name456 |   0 |         |   0.00 |
+----+---------+-----+---------+--------+
1 row in set (0,02 sec)

mysql> UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET Name = INSERT(Name, 6, 0, ' ');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from CUSTOMERS;
+----+----------+-----+---------+--------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS | SALARY |
+----+----------+-----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Name4 56 |   0 |         |   0.00 |
+----+----------+-----+---------+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Here is an example:

mysql> SELECT INSERT('Name456', 6, 0, ' ');
+------------------------------+
| INSERT('Name456', 6, 0, ' ') |
+------------------------------+
| Name4 56                     |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

Comment: let us start from very beginning: what is a purpose of such modifying? Just change a column name? if yes: 
ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;

Comment: No i want change the content like i mentioned up.
From the column "Name" with the content "name1234" i want add a space at the position 4 so that the result is "name 1234"

Comment: try command from the post:
UPDATE Customers
SET Name = INSERT(Name, 6, 0, ' ');


I've just updated the post with an example.

Comment: Okay i have tried it but i get an error = "near FROM syntax error"

Comment: UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET Name = INSERT(Name, 6, 0, ' ');

there is no FROM condition

Comment: provide us with a database type and version and full text of query and error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH  My_string(some_text) AS (VALUES ('This is some text') )

SELECT

   some_text,

   CAST ( (WITH RECURSIVE Counter(x) AS ( VALUES ( ( 1 ) ) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM Counter WHERE x < length(some_text) )

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(substr(some_text, x, 1),' ') FROM counter)
       AS TEXT) Some_text_With_Spaces

FROM My_string
```

You are getting the length of the string and creating a temp table with a count from 1 to the length then using `GROUP_CONCAT` with `SUBSTR` to pull each character out and use the specified delimiter.  In the above example a space.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT STUFF(name, 5, 0, ' ') FROM Customers
```